# Jquery Ajax load method

Tags: jquery, ajax

All , forgive me I am a newbie of jquery .I found there doesn't exist more detail of this api in [jquery load api](http://api.jquery.com/load/).
Here is what I had lean from it and I have some the question about it.please review it.

This api include these ways of usage to make a ajax call.

- `$('#result').load('ajax/test.html');` //ajax load a html file , it use
  `Get` method.
- `$('#result').load('ajax/test.html .someclass');` //ajax load the
  selected content from a html file.
- `$('#result').load('ajax/test.html', function() {   alert('Load was
  performed.');});`//call back when it succeed.
- `$(document).ready(function(){   $("input").keyup(function(){
     txt=$("input").val();
     $("span").load("/jquery/gethint.asp",{suggest:txt});   }); });`//I am not sure what is this `data` mean. How the server side get this `data`?

So far , I didn't find the example when data is a string which will add in the url as parameters by jquery. I hope someone also can illustrate some code for me . thanks.

**Updated**

Please note the `load`api always be with the `serialize` method to format the UI input values to json. thanks.

Comment: Data is string. What do you want?

Comment: Data could be string / array / object, I am not sure how to get the data from the server side .thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `data` in jQuery [`$.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) can be given in these ways.

- **As a JSON object.**

  ```
    data: {"foo": "bar"}
  ```
- **As a string**

  ```
    data: "foo=bar"
  ```

You can use both the ways. The first one is the object way.

---

For your four queries:

- Yes, you are right. It uses `GET` method.
- From a HTML file, and with that particular class's HTML. Not sure if classes are accepted, but I have used ID.
- Yes, you are right. Executes some JavaScript after the AJAX Request is done.
- This `data` is explained above.

---

#### Server Side Script

**PHP**

```
<?php
  if (!isset($_GET['foo']) && $_GET['foo'] == "bar")
    die("true");
  else
    die("false");
?>
```

**ASP**

```
<%
  IF Request.Form("foo") = "bar" Then
    Response.Write "true"
  ELSE
    Response.Write "false"
  END IF
%>
```

Comment: @Joe.wang That's what I said. I haven't tried it, so I should not comment! :P

Comment: you answer is very good.but if you can show us the server side code , it will be appreciated. thanks.Anyway,

Comment: What kind of server side code do you want? I don't get you. Anyways, I will give for ASP and well as PHP. Give some time.

Comment: @Joe.wang Kindly confirm the ASP Code. Its been years using it.

Comment: I almost forgot the asp. :P ,It works well. It is very kind of you . thanks!

Comment: It is almost 23 o'clock here, I have to get up early tomorrow morning. good night . hope you kind guys have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

there are different ways to use Ajax in jQuery, with the basic one being .ajax().

Here are some useful shorthand methods: http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/shorthand-methods/

These methods do the same as ajax, only with easier syntax and preconfigured to do specific tasks.

I'm not sure i understood your question, but i'll answer for any interpertation of your question:

1. if you want to send a parameter to the server, you use the second parameter of the load function to send a parameter, as such:

   ```
   $('#result').load('ajax/test.html', {prop:val, prop2:val});
   ```

   these props will be added to your request (either by get or by post methods, as per configuration)
2. if you wish to recieve the data from the server into a parameter, you use the following:

   ```
   $('#result').load('ajax/test.html', function(data){ console.log(data); });
   ```

   in this case, function is a callback that runs once the request is complete, and data holds all of the contents of the response from the server.

Comment: Just edited to make some code formatting, hope you don't mind. :)

Comment: @Rodik , It is very helpful link. I can't vote it up for more times. I think `load` is one of the helpful api in them. thanks you very much.